# Postgres_log table import not captuirng SQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

While importing postgres log,sql is not inserting into table query column:

[image]

Comment: How are you importing the postgres log?  Is this some 3rd party tool?

Comment: using:COPY postgres_log FROM '/full/path/to/logfile.csv' WITH csv;

Answer (score 0):

Not all log messages include the query text.  log_duration, for example, just logs the duration, not the text of the query.  If the query text isn't in the csv file to start with, it won't get populated into the table.

Using log_min_duration_statement=0 rather than log_duration will log both the duration and the text of all queries.

Comment: log_min_duration_statement=0  and log_duration both on .Few queries capturing with stderr but not with CSV. No proper document with pros and concerns or with full details.

Comment: Few places duration present but not text and other way around in few cases ,is there any reason as I have enabled all parameters.